# how to upload image from angularjs to google endpoint using java blobstore API

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload image form angularjs to google appengine using java api in Datastore. but i don't have proper code for uploading image on Blobstore Java API.

any one please share me code.

my frontend - Angularjs
Backend - java API for Datastore

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably best be served by using the `FileReader` Api.

```
function create_blob(file) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
        deferred.resolve(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  return deferred.promise;
}
```